# VB.Net Reverse DataTable Order

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable, rows, reverse

What's the easiest way to review the order of a DataTable?

```
    ' Clean Table
    dtRows.Columns.Add("date", GetType(DateTime))
    For Each row In dtRows.Rows
        row("date") = DateTime.Parse(row(0).ToString.Replace("""", ""))
    Next

    ' Remove Old Col
    dtRows.Columns.Remove("Column1")

    ' Sort
    dtRows.DefaultView.Sort = "date ASC"
```

Is doing nothing for me, so I'd rather just have a loop reverse it.

I've tried recreating a new column with the DateTime Type and removing the old column and sorting by that, it just isn't working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to view the DataTable sorted is to use a `DataView`.

```
 Dim dv As DataView = dtRows.DefaultView
```

The `dtRows.DefaultView.Sort = "date ASC"` will set the default sort if you set it before creating the DataView.  To scan through the `dataview`, you would use the following:

```
For Each row As DataRowView In dv
  'Do something
Next
```